# MSIL store a value of structure to return

Tags: c#, .net, cil, il

I am using RemotingLite library ([see at github](https://github.com/MatterHackers/RemotingLite)) and have an issue with Proxy class factory.
In few words the issue is when generating code for return an `ValueType` objects like user defined structures.

Here a part of original code:

```
...
mIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, resultLB.LocalIndex); //load the result array
mIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 0); //load the index of the return value. Alway 0
mIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldelem_Ref); //load the value in the index of the array

if (returnType.IsValueType)
{
    mIL.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox, returnType); //unbox it
    mIL.Emit(ldindOpCodeTypeMap[returnType]);
}
else
    mIL.Emit(OpCodes.Castclass, returnType);
}
        mIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

`ldindOpCodeTypeMap` is a dictionary with opcodes like `OpCodes.Ldind_U2` etc. So it works only for standard MSIL types like `Int16, Int32` etc. But what I need to do if I need to push to stack then return a custom `ValueType` value (for example - `Guid` - size is 16 bytes)?

For example:

```
...
mIL.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox, returnType); //unbox it
OpCode opcode;
if (ldindOpCodeTypeMap.TryGetValue(returnType, out opcode))
{
    mIL.Emit(ldindOpCodeTypeMap[returnType]);
}
else
{
    // here I getting the size of custom type
    var size = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(returnType);
    // what next?
}
...
```

Here I have get a size of custom `ValueType` value. So how Load a value of custom `ValueType` onto the evaluation stack indirectly like `Ldind_`x opcodes do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ldobj will do what you want.  But you could also replace the entire conditional with Unbox_Any: it will do everything you need for a value type or a reference type.

The full replacement for your posted code would be:

```
...
mIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, resultLB.LocalIndex); //load the result array
mIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 0); //load the index of the return value. Alway 0
mIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldelem_Ref); //load the value in the index of the array

mIL.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox_Any, returnType);
mIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```